# Debugging a JS file using IE 9 Debugger-why so many scripts listed?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, javascript-debugger

I am trying to use the F12 Internet debugging Tool that comes with - yes, Internet Explorer 9. Don't ask...

When I click on the Scripts tab, there is a drop down of javascript files that have been downloaded. to set a break point in one of  my script files, I click the drop down and select the JS file. Normally, this list isn't that long, but I've been seeing 100's of scripts that have names such as "poll?transport=longpolling&..@#$@#$@#&@#$@#" and I have to scroll throough this very, very long list until I find my JS file.

What are all these files and is there a better way to locate the JS script I want to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a SignalR connection. Most likely it's the Browser Link feature from Visual Studio - I believe that uses SignalR internally.

You can disable it from the dropdown next to Visual Studio's refresh icon:
[image: Enable Browser Link is the 3rd of 4 options and is checked by default]